# Multiple X-Frame-Option refuses to show in-frame

Tags: php, apache, iframe, http-headers, x-frame-options

I have an awful situation

A website with **Apache2+Php5.6**, one of the pages of the site has a `<iframe>` tag but it refuses to load because **X-Frame-Options** was set in more than one php file inside the web archives with differentes values (DENY and SAMEORIGIN) falling to DENY.

> Refused to display '*webpage*' in a frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('DENY, SAMEORIGIN'). Falling back to 'deny'.

I try to set X-Frame-Option in security.conf or with .htaccess but when the page use that particular file, it overrides the value and finish into the same situation.

> Refused to display '*webpage*' in a frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('**SAMEORIGIN**,DENY, SAMEORIGIN'). Falling back to 'deny'.

My questions

- ¿Is there a way to override all response headers of my page?, or
- ¿Is it posible to find in which php file X-Frame-Option was set?

I know that is posible to disable X-Frame-Option but **i don't want that** if there is any other posible solution or workaround.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE

It was a nginx server working as reverse proxy in top of my configuration with that property settet to DENY, hoppefully i manage to reach that configuration and now it work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can check the response headers in the Network tab in developer tools to check which responses come with which X-Frame-Options value.

You can override X-Frame-Options in modern browsers by specifying Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors directive in a response header. Use Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self';